# Wordpress query based on ACF Datepicker values results in no posts

Tags: php, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

So I added some custom fields to the post posttype, namely event_startdate and event_enddate. My goal is to show all events that are currently ongoing (so current date is between start and enddate). However, no posts are showing up with my current code.

This is what I've got:

```
<?php
        $today = date('Ymd');

        $args = array (
            'posts_per_page'         => '9',
            'order'                  => 'ASC',
            'orderby'                => 'id',
          'meta_query'             => array(
              array(
                'key'     => 'event_startdate',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => $today
              ),
              array(
                'key'     =>  'event_enddate',
                'compare' =>  '<=',
                'value'   => $today
              )
          )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
```

and then the rest of the loop. I know the loop works, because all posts show up when the meta_query is removed. What could the issue be? I've experimented with some different dateformats (hardcoded), but that didn't seem to fix it. Tried other solutions posted online as well, but none seemed to fix the issue.

EDIT: Started working on another query in the meantime, this time using event_featured, a TRUE/FALSE field. Code is the same as the previously mentioned code, except for the args. Doesn't return posts either:

```
     $args = array (
        'post_type'              => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'         => '9',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'orderby'                => 'id',
      'meta_query'             => array(
          array(
              'key' => 'event_featured',
              'value' => '1',
              'compare' => '=='
          )
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I created the fields in PHP. Using the admin interface to create them worked for me. So if you're also struggling with this, delete your fields in php and create them again in Wordpress.

If you want to include them with your theme, export the fields to PHP code with the export tool in ACF.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see in your code where you declared the post type to query. Add the post type to the query, see the first line after the first array. Try use this:

```
    $args = array (
        'post_type'              =>'posttype',
        'posts_per_page'         => '9',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'orderby'                => 'id',
      'meta_query'             => array(
          array(
            'key'     => 'event_startdate',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value'   => $today
          ),
          array(
            'key'     =>  'event_enddate',
            'compare' =>  '<=',
            'value'   => $today
          )
      )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
```

Comment: It's the default value (post), so it that shouldn't matter :P Didn't work for me at least.